How can we know for sure we are going to heaven?
Do you know for sure you are going to Heaven.
https://marymargretsamerica.blogspot.com/2024/11/the-christ-child_69.html

Search the phrase “assurance of salvation” on this site and many questions will show up. They address Catholic, Reformed, LDS, Methodist and other denominational views. Answers also comment on views of Augustine and other early church fathers.

Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange. Your question, as it stands, may be closed because it does not meet with our requirements. It is likely to elicit opinion-based answers.  Please take our tour and then edit your question: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

"If ye have faith, and doubt not" (Matthew 21:21) — If one doubts salvation, one lacks true faith. "Dress for the job you want, not the job you have." isn't only literal advice.

This question was seriously discussed and according 1Cor 4, 4-5 you cannot be sure with your salvation until your death. I guess it was one of questions given to Joan of Arc at her inquisition court.

Believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you will be saved...translated from death to life...from the kingdom of darkness to the kingdom of light.
This is well attested in the scriptures and interpreted in a myriad of ways.
The apostle John tells us, in his first epistle, that once a person believes in such a way the testimony that God has given regarding Jesus becomes internalized (many see this as a Divine indwelling):

He that believeth on the Son of God hath the witness in himself: he that believeth not God hath made him a liar; because he believeth not the record that God gave of his Son.  And this is the record, that God hath given to us eternal life, and this life is in his Son.  He that hath the Son hath life; and he that hath not the Son of God hath not life - 1 John 5:10-12

The life of the son of God lived through faith, which works by love, produces assurance. John's first epistle addresses this a number of different times and his stated purpose for the epistle is that we might know that we have eternal life.
The more we are trusting in Christ alone, the greater our assurance and the more we trust in Christ plus something else, or just something else, the weaker our assurance.
Notice that I have not stated that a person can lose their salvation. However, assurance can be devastated through faithless living:  A shipwrecked faith.

'Going to heaven' means, for most people, their hoped-for state after death (or, immediately, when the Lord returns, for those who believe he will, instantly, judge all and bring all of the old creation to an end).
But the better question, more in keeping with the four gospel accounts of Jesus' ministry, would be 'How can I be sure that I have entered (now) the kingdom of heaven ?'
If I am now in the kingdom of heaven ; if I have been granted eternal life, as a result of believing in Jesus Christ ; then how shall I know that ?
Well, there are certain marks of a true believer. There are certain characteristics by which true believers are known. Every epistle of the New Testament contains descriptions of 'the saints' 'the faithful' 'those born again' 'the regenerate' 'the called' 'the elect'.
It would take pages to list out all the references.
We are exhorted to 'make our calling and election sure', 2 Peter 1:10, and it is the exercise of every called person to do so as they carefully tread a spiritual path through this adverse, sinful and tempting world.
'He that endureth to the end, shall be saved', Mark 24:13, should be borne in mind throughout this life.
Paul, at one stage of his pilgrimage, stated 'I keep my body under, lest, having preached to others, I, myself, should be a castaway', 1 Corinthians 9:27.  But, later, in older age, he was certain that 'Henceforth there is laid up for me a crown of righteousness, which the Lord, the righteous judge, shall give me at that day' 2 Timothy 4:8.
It is improper to be over-confident as one starts out on a journey, that one will achieve the final goal.
It becomes more certain as progress is made, as obstacles are overcome, as experience of the way is gained - that the venture will be successful.
'Let not him that putteth on the harness, boast as he that taketh it off
again', 1 Kings 20:11, is true of every kind of warfare ; but especially is it true of our spiritual conflict, as we seek a victory that shall be endless.
I hope this is of some help to you.

You cannot know if you will go to heaven, you can only hope

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Paul seems fairly certain about the crown he was going to receive, It is a question of spiritual maturity.

Things hoped for have never become a surety for even Paul himself has not ascended into heaven but one son of man
